# MySQL error 1064 on creating a table query

Tags: php, html, database, forms, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `chuchutvlogin`. (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
 `gender` CHAR(1) NOT NULL , 
 `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
 `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
 `number` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

what's issue?

i was creating a login databse and error #1064 came syntax error in localhost phpmyadmnin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix syntax error in your query, remove dot char after table name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE chuchutvlogin (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    number BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hZOgp6oe)